# ESLint giving 'no-unused-vars' error for instantiating variable and then assigning value

Tags: javascript, eslint

This throws an error:

```
var foo = 0;
foo = 1;
```

Seems weird that it's considered wrong. Can I change this behavior in my .eslintrc configuration? The documentation doesn't seem to cover this use case.

Comment: Uh, but you *are* never using the variable? Your code treats it like [WOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory_(joke)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off `no-unused-vars` completely by adding: `"no-unused-vars: 0` to your .eslintrc config file. The rule is reports any variable that is not used and can be safely deleted from the code. If you just assign value to a variable, but don't use that value anywhere in your code, then you can safely remove the variable all together. Assigning a value is not considered "use".